# JS file not loaded before constructor is called

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, web-applications

I have an issue where I have code in a constructor of a component in Meteor.
What this should do is open a socket etc and get ready for connections.

What  currently happens is when the page is refreshed it tells me that there is a reference error and that `Peer` is not defined.

If I however put the code inside its own function and call that function when a button I add to the page is clicked then it works fine.

This leads me to believe that it is related to the constructor being called before the file `Peer.js` is loaded?

Meteor has a function called `ComponentDidMount()` and if I put the code in there I still get the same error as if it was placed in the constructor.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class WebChat extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this shows on refresh, still get error next though
    alert("Mounted");

    // Create a Peer instance
    window.peer = new Peer({
      key: 'key',  // get a free key at http://peerjs.com/peerserver
      debug: 3,
      config: {
        'iceServers': [
          {url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
          {url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
        ]
      }
    });

    // Handle event: upon opening our connection to the PeerJS server
    peer.on('open', function () {
      $('#myPeerId').text(peer.id);
    });

    // Handle event: remote peer receives a call
    peer.on('call', function (incomingCall) {
      window.currentCall = incomingCall;
      incomingCall.answer(window.localStream);
      incomingCall.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
        window.remoteStream = remoteStream;
        var video = document.getElementById("theirVideo")
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream);
      });
    });

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    // get audio/video
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function (stream) {
        //display video
        var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        window.localStream = stream;
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  connectToPeer() { // If I use this instead of the componentDidMount then it works, but requires me to click a button first
    // Create a Peer instance
    window.peer = new Peer({
      key: 'key',  // get a free key at http://peerjs.com/peerserver
      debug: 3,
      config: {
        'iceServers': [
          {url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
          {url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
        ]
      }
    });

    // Handle event: upon opening our connection to the PeerJS server
    peer.on('open', function () {
      $('#myPeerId').text(peer.id);
    });

    // Handle event: remote peer receives a call
    peer.on('call', function (incomingCall) {
      window.currentCall = incomingCall;
      incomingCall.answer(window.localStream);
      incomingCall.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
        window.remoteStream = remoteStream;
        var video = document.getElementById("theirVideo")
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream);
      });
    });

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    // get audio/video
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function (stream) {
        //display video
        var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        window.localStream = stream;
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  makeCall() {
    var outgoingCall = peer.call($('#remotePeerId').val(), window.localStream);
    window.currentCall = outgoingCall;
    outgoingCall.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
      window.remoteStream = remoteStream;
      var video = document.getElementById("theirVideo");
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream);
    });
  }

  endCall() {
    window.currentCall.close();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Video Chat</h2>
        <div id="video-container">
          Their video: <video id="theirVideo" class="theirVideo" autoplay></video>
          Your video: <video id="myVideo" muted="true" class="myVideo" autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <h2>Controls</h2>
        <div>
          <p>Your id: <span id="myPeerId">...</span></p>
          <p>Make a call</p><br/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Call user id..." id="remotePeerId"/>
          <p><a href="#" id="makeCall" onClick={this.makeCall.bind(this)}>Call</a></p>
          <p><a href="#" id="endCall" onClick={this.endCall.bind(this)}>End call</a></p>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#" id="endCall" onClick={this.connectToPeer.bind(this)}>Connect to peer</a></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `Peer` is not defined in the component, nor imported; the error is accurate.

Comment: But it works with I click a button that calls the same code so how is it that works?

Comment: If you're just acquiring Peer via a script tag include in HTML, then you're dealing with a race condition, I'd suggest installing the lib via npm and then importing it in your component.

Comment: This means running npm install <some lib>, then using the same import syntax as your React and ReactDOM imports.